# google sheet script yes no and X dialog box

Tags: google-sheets

Hi everyone could someone show me how to get this script to quit when the X is press rigth now it looks like it's doing the same as if i press no
any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks

```
function ticketSaveEmailYesNo(){
// Display a dialog box with a message and "Yes" and "No" buttons. The user 
//can also close the
// dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.alert(
 'Please Confirm',
 'Email a copy of this ticket to the client', 
 ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

 // Process the user's response.
 if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
 ticketSaveAndMail();
 } else {
   ticketSavePDF()
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change 'Process the user's response' to

```
 if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
  ticketSaveAndMail();
 }
 if (response == ui.Button.NO) {
  ticketSavePDF()
 }
else {

 }
 }
```

This will handle the NO response. The else will handle the X.